# Не могу использовать systemctl внутри контейнера Docker с установленной rocky linux 9.2

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, systemctl, dnf

Не могу использовать systemctl внутри контейнера Docker с установленной rocky linux 9.2.(образ взят официальный,[dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/rockylinux/9.2/images/sha256-3387f6adc2fcdba59b9ff07acb955b4dbb610d3d93f7c68182107c1d25fac39c?context=explore))
При написании команды systemctl выскакивает сообщение

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Не помогает dnf reinstall systemd - просто переустанавливает:

[image: dnf reinstall systemd]

Пробовал полностью удалить пакет dnf remove systemd (autoremove - аналогично), но пишет

```
Error: 
Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: 
systemd
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not 
only best candidate packages)
```

Пробую с ключами --skip-broken и --nobest, все равно остается проблема:

```
Error: 
Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages:
```

Подскажите, люди добрые, как победить проблему?

Comment: Оно? https://stackoverflow.com/q/27947865